# Transforming variables in rstan (bayesian analysis)

Tags: r, bayesian, stan

I am new to Bayesian analysis and am trying to use rstan to estimate the posterior density distribution. The exercise is attempting to re-create an example given to us by my university using stan but I am a bit confused as to how to properly transform variables. My current code runs without error but the result doesn't match what we were given by the university (albeit close), graph below for clarity with stan estimates in black. I got the code to work by consulting the manual and piecing random bits together but in particular I am not too sure why `target` is needed and if the transformation of gamma is indeed correct. Any guidance would be appreciated!

**Model**

[image]

**Stan Code**

```
data {
  int<lower=0> I;
  int<lower=0> n[I];
  int<lower=0> x[I];
  real<lower=0> a;
  real<lower=0> b;
  real m;
  real<lower=0> p;
}

parameters {
  real<lower=0> lambda;
  real mu;
  real<lower=0, upper=1> theta[I];
}

transformed parameters {
  real gam[I];
  for( j in 1:I)
   gam[j] = log(theta[j] / (1-theta[j])) ;
}


model {
  target +=  gamma_lpdf( lambda |  a, b);
  target +=  normal_lpdf( mu | m , 1/sqrt(p));
  target +=  normal_lpdf( gam | mu, 1/sqrt(lambda));
  target +=  binomial_lpmf( x | n , theta);
}
```

**R code**

```
library(rstan)
fit <- stan(
  file = "hospital.stan" , 
  data = dat , 
  iter = 20000,
  warmup = 2000,   
  chains = 1
)
```

**dat**

```
structure(
  list(
      I = 12L, 
      n = c(47, 211, 810, 148, 196, 360, 119,  207, 97, 256, 148, 215), 
      x = c(0, 8, 46, 9, 13, 24, 8, 14, 8, 29, 18, 31), 
      a = 2, 
      b = 2, 
      m = 0, 
      p = 0.01), 
  .Names = c("I", "n", "x", "a", "b", "m", "p")
)
```

**---UPDATE with solution---**

The issue as pointed out by Ben Goodrich is that I was deriving gamma from theta where as it should have been the other way around as gamma is my random variable. The correct stan code is below.

```
data {
    int<lower=0> I;
    int<lower=0> n[I];
    int<lower=0> x[I];
    real<lower=0> a;
    real<lower=0> b;
    real m;
    real<lower=0> p;
}

parameters {
    real<lower=0> lambda;
    real mu;
    real gam[I];
}

transformed parameters {
    real<lower=0 , upper=1> theta[I];
    // theta = inv_logit(gam);  // Alternatively can use the in-built inv_logit function which is vectorised
    for(j in 1:I){
        theta[j] = 1 / ( 1 + exp(-gam[j]));
    }
}

model {
    target +=  gamma_lpdf( lambda |  a, b);
    target +=  normal_lpdf( mu | m , 1/sqrt(p));
    target +=  normal_lpdf( gam | mu, 1/sqrt(lambda));
    target +=  binomial_lpmf( x | n ,  theta );
}
```

Comment: The `transformed data` block is only executed once; the `transformed parameters` block is executed many times per iteration of the Markov Chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a hint, try putting `gam`(ma) in the `parameters` block and then declare and define `theta` in the `transformed parameters` block according to distributions you gave at the outset.

Beginners to Stan often assume that Stan is endowed with the ability to logically work out the implications of your Stan program, when really it gets transpiled fairly literally to C++ and the lines of code from `transformed parameters` and `model` blocks are executed over and over again.

The reason why it makes a difference whether `gam`(ma) or `theta` is the primitive parameter has to do with the change-of-variables principle. If you really wanted to, you could get the same results with your original parameterization if you added a Jacobian determinant term (in log units) to `target`, but it is easier to avoid that by moving `gam`(ma) to the `parameters` block and `theta` to the `transformed parameters` block. For details about the change-of-variables principle, see this [case study](http://mc-stan.org/documentation/case-studies/mle-params.html).

Comment: This fixed it! Before I mark as the answer could you possible help explain why this fixed it ?  I would have thought having theta as a function of gamma  or having gamma as a function of theta should be interchangeable ?

Comment: Having said that I am now thinking that its because gamma is the rv that we are sampling from a normal distribution whilst theta is a function of that rv.